# Scroll horizontal active item using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I need the first active item active and when scrolling to the left, you activate the next item, and also when you return, you must return correctly. Always centering the box for the selected item.
Tks

```
onScroll(event) {

this.currentScroll = this.panel.nativeElement.scrollLeft;

this.arrayScroll.push(this.panel.nativeElement.scrollLeft);

let count = this.arrayScroll.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

this.arrayScroll.forEach((elem, index) => {
  if (this.arrayScroll[index] >= this.list[this.indexLabel].size / 2) {
    if (this.arrayScroll[index] >= this.soma) {
      this.list.length >= this.indexLabel ? (this.indexLabel += 1) : (this.indexLabel = 0);
      this.soma = this.soma + this.list[this.indexLabel - 1].size;

     this.selectItem(this.indexLabel);
    }
  } else if (this.panel.nativeElement.scrollLeft <= this.soma) {

    this.list.length >= this.indexLabel ? (this.indexLabel -= 1) : (this.indexLabel = 0);
    this.soma -= this.list[this.indexLabel].size;
      this.selectItem(this.indexLabel);
  }
});
```

}

[Example animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Awb.gif)

Code: Click on the first item to activate [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-94kc2y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.ts)